# PhP cannot seem to find basic linux commands

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I use Webuzo panel, PHP5.6, and Apache with Wordpress (Ubuntu 16)

Whenever a wordpress plugin attempts to run a script, I've greeted with:

```
sh: 1: wc: not found, referer:
sh: 1: awk: not found, referer:
sh: 1: cut: not found, referer:
```

or pretty much any other basic linux command.

I've set the following flag in php.ini to try to fix this (as I've assumed its a path problem :

```
include_path = "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

This doesn't seem to affect the issue at all.

Any clue on how to clear this up?